# Amend img src using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'd like to change the paths to images in the following way (essentially removing the "-00x00" dimensions section), so that these examples:

```
<img src="/uploads/lorem_m_1-375x349.png">
<img src="/uploads/ipsum_m_1-248x378.png">
<img src="/uploads/dolor_m_1-392x298.png">
```

Become:

```
<img src="/uploads/lorem_m_1.png">
<img src="/uploads/ipsum_m_1.png">
<img src="/uploads/dolor_m_1.png">
```

Thank you.

Comment: With jquery, you would simply change the attribute using the `.attr` method. `$("img").attr("src",function(i,src){return fixSrc(src);})`

Comment: It is recommended to use prop over attr in this situation.

Comment: @JonathanW the src property reflects the value of the src attribute, therefore it's perfectly fine to use .attr to modify it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Comment: Why is my question rated negatively? I researched before I asked, and tried to be clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LexfH/1/):

```
<img src="/uploads/lorem_m_1-375x349.png">
<img src="/uploads/ipsum_m_1-248x378.png">
<img src="/uploads/dolor_m_1-392x298.png">
```

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');

    $(this).attr('src',replaceNumbers(src));

    //console.log($(this).attr('src'));

});

function replaceNumbers(str) {
     var regex = /-\d+x\d+/;

    return str.replace(regex,'');     
}
```

*replaceNumbers()* simply takes a string (in this case, your image source) and replaces the '-00x00' with *empty string*.  Then, it returns that string, and in the jQuery *each* method, each image source is replaced with its changed value.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the quick and thorough answer, Josh. Worked great.